# SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
for i in range(0,len(donor_df)):
    if donor_df['cand_nm'][i] == 'Obama, Barack':
        donor_df['Party'] = 'Democrat'
    else:
        donor_df['Party'] = 'Republican'
```

`donor_df` is a dataframe want to create a new column named 'party' but its not giving an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `np.where`

```
donor_df['Party']=np.where(donor_df['cand_nm'] == 'Obama, Barack','Democrat','Republican')
```

Comment: thanks man it worked but can you also tell me why the above written program is not working

Comment: @Ben.hardy `donor_df['cand_nm'].iloc[i]` I guess your index is not start with 1 to len(df)